# Can’t map an array from state inside of my component when it comes from a hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

**Question:** Why am I unable to map an array from the state inside of my component?

**Background:**

1. Component successfully dispatches API call on mount using `React.useEffect()`.
2. Component will not map the array to return child components in table. (but the dummy-data works)
3. When checking what is accessible in the component it appears that the static dummy-data and the actual state-full data are both similar in structure, and available.

[console log for both arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAI82.png)

```
ObservationList.js:45 (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
ObservationList.js:46 (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

However, when I try to pass `observations` instead of `rows`  to the map function inside of `return()`  I get an error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
```

It works just fine when passing the dummy data.

The component file:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';

import { requestAllObservations } from "./actions";
import Title from '../Title/Title';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  seeMore: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));

// // Dummy data that works
function createData(_id, date, type, severity, assetCompany, status) {
  return { _id, date, type, severity, assetCompany, status };
}
const rows = [
  createData(0, '16 Mar, 2019', 'Exposure', 'Medium', 'Pipeline Co', 'New'),
  createData(1, '16 Mar, 2019', 'Leak', 'Critical', 'Pipeline Co', 'New'),
  createData(2, '16 Mar, 2019', 'Debris', 'low', 'Pipeline Co', 'New'),
  createData(3, '16 Mar, 2019', 'Debris', 'Medium', 'Pipeline Co', 'New'),
  createData(4, '16 Mar, 2019', 'Exposure', 'Medium', 'Pipeline Co', 'New'),
  createData(5, '16 Mar, 2019', 'Debris', 'Medium', 'Pipeline Co', 'New'),
  createData(6, '16 Mar, 2019', 'Leak', 'Critical', 'Pipeline Co', 'New'),
  createData(7, '16 Mar, 2019', 'Debris', 'low', 'Pipeline Co', 'New'),
  createData(8, '16 Mar, 2019', 'Debris', 'Medium', 'Pipeline Co', 'New'),
  createData(9, '16 Mar, 2019', 'Exposure', 'Medium', 'Pipeline Co', 'New')
];
// //

export const ObservationList = (props) => {

  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleRefresh = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(rows)
    console.log(observations)
  }

  const observations = useSelector(state => state.observations.observations)
  const token = useSelector(state => state.auth.token)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(requestAllObservations(token))
  }, [false])

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Title>Observations</Title>
      <Table size="small">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Date</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Type</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Severity</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Company</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Status</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row) => (
            <TableRow key={row._id}>
              <TableCell>{row.createdAt}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.type}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.severity}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.assetCompany}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.status}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
      <div className={classes.seeMore}>
        <Link color="primary" href="#" onClick={handleRefresh}>
          refresh
        </Link>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default ObservationList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `state.observations.observations` is null until your request finishes.

So, you can fix the issue by either making a separate loading state of your component that displays a loading spinner or something until your observations are populated.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(requestAllObservations(token))
  }, [false])

  if(!observations) return 'Loading...'      

  return (
  ... (rest of return block)
```

---

Or you can fix it by guarding against a falsy value before you map it.

```
      {rows && rows.map((row) => (
        <TableRow key={row._id}>
          <TableCell>{row.createdAt}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{row.type}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{row.severity}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{row.assetCompany}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{row.status}</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      ))}
```

---

Or you can fix it by making the observations have a default of an empty array if it's falsy. If you use this, you might want to define an empty 'stub' array outside of the component and use that instead of `[]` within the component. That way the default value won't change references every re-render.

```
const observations = useSelector(state => state.observations.observations) || []
```

Comment: Thank you Zach. I chose options three, worked like a charm. I appreciate it.